# Problems when setting ranges to variants

Tags: arrays, vba, excel, variant

**EDITED** to fix typo and add more details

I think you can see what I want to do here:

```
Dim bMatch As Boolean
Dim vCriteria As Variant
Dim rCell As Range
Dim vCellArray() As Variant

    If rCell = "" Then
        'Do nothing
    Else
        For Each vCriteria In vCriteriaArray
            If InStr(1, rCell, ",") Then
                ReDim vCellArray(0 To Len(rCell) - Len(Replace(rCell, ",", "")))
                vCellArray = CVar(Split(rCell, ","))
            Else
                ReDim vCellArray(0 To 0)
                vCellArray(0) = rCell
            End If
            If UBound(Filter(vCellArray, vCriteria)) > -1 Then
                bMatch = True
                Exit For
            End If
        Next vCriteria
        If bMatch = False Then
            rCell.EntireRow.Hidden = True
        End If
    End If
Next rCell
```

I want to read the contents from rCell, split it based on a comma delimiter and store it in a variant array.

However the statement

```
vCellArra = CVar(Split(rCell, ","))
```

stops working if the following statements have happened before

```
ReDim vCellArray(0 To 0)
vCellArray(0) = rCell
```

I tried ReDimin the array

```
ReDim vCellArray(0 To Len(rCell) - Len(Replace(rCell, ",", "")))
```

But that didn't help.

How can I change the code so that I can accomplish my objective **"to read the contents from rCell, split it based on a comma delimiter and store it in a variant array"** no matter if there are commas in rCell or not?

Comment: What is `vCellArra`?

Comment: Is the `vCellArra` a typo here only ? You're overwriting the result  on each loop, is it what you really want ?

Comment: Sorry, that's a typo. I have added more code to show you more of what I am trying to do. I have intended to overwrite the result on each loop. That is what is causing the problems. When I have set ReDim vCellArray(0 To 0)
vCellArray(0) = rCell once, vCellArra = CVar(Split(rCell, ",")) no longer works. Maybe there is a smarter way to rewrite the function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That appears to be equivalent to simply this:

```
If rCell = "" Then
    'Do nothing
Else
    For Each vCriteria In vCriteriaArray
        If InStr(1, "," & rCell.Value & ",", "," & vCriteria & ",", vbTextCompare) <> 0 Then
            bMatch = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next vCriteria
    If Not bMatch Then rCell.EntireRow.Hidden = True
End If
```

Comment: It's pretty good. But I think it's not equivalent. In the problem I posted I check for example if vCriteria "House" has a match in rCell "Big House, Small House, Skyscraper". I think that your code would match "House" with both "Big House" and "Small House", but I want it to not match, because there is not exact comma delimited match to "House".

Comment: I think you are unaware that Filter finds values that contain the string you specify, not that are exact matches. See edited code above.

Comment: Ahha, I didn't know that. too bad. Tank you for your solution though!